# Cross field validation in Angular2

Tags: javascript, validation, angular

I'm building an Angular2 client side application.  I'm currently working on the membership components and integrating client side components with MVC6 vNext Identity v3.  I have written custom Angular2 password validators as follows:

```
needsCapitalLetter(ctrl: Control): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if(!ctrl.value.match(/[A-Z]/))
        return {'needsCapitalLetter': true}

    return null;
}

needsLowerLetter(ctrl: Control): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if(!ctrl.value.match(/[a-z]/))
        return {'needsLowerLetter': true}

    return null;            
}

needsNumber(ctrl: Control): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if(!ctrl.value.match(/\d/))
        return {'needsNumber': true}

    return null;            
}

needsSpecialCharacter(ctrl: Control): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if(!ctrl.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/))
        return {'needsSpecialCharacter': true}

    return null;            
}
```

This work great, and I'm loving Angular2, but now I'm trying to write a validator that verifies that the "Confirm Password" is equal to the "Password".  In order to do this, I need to be able to validate one field against the other.  I can easily do this at the component level, and just check on blur, or on submit, or any number of other ways, but this bypasses the Angular2 ngForm validation system.  I would very much like to figure out how to write an Angular2 Validator for a field that can check the value of another field, by passing in the name of the other field or something close to this.  It seems this should be a capability as this would be a necessity in almost any complex business application UI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 validator which relies on multiple form fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788681/angular2-validator-which-relies-on-multiple-form-fields)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to assign a custom validator to a complete form group to implement this. Something like this:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name:  ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]
  matchingPasswords: this.fb.group({
    password:        ['', Validators.required],
    confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
  }, {validator: this.matchValidator})  <--------
});
```

This way you will have access to all controls of the group and not only one... This can be accessed using the `controls` property of the FormGroup. The FormGroup is provided when validation is triggered. For example:

```
matchValidator(group: FormGroup) {
  var valid = false;

  for (name in group.controls) {
    var val = group.controls[name].value
    (...)
  }

  if (valid) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    mismatch: true
  };
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular2 validator which relies on multiple form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788681/angular2-validator-which-relies-on-multiple-form-fields)

Comment: This seems like the right way until you try to send form.value over to your back-end, and you realize its sending your matching passwords object with both passwords. Any elegant solutions beyond deleting matching passwords and adding password before sending it over?

Comment: How do I define the password field in html? I found things like `<div ngFormControl="matchingPassword">` which seems not to be up to date anymore.

Comment: Little update here. In the newest Angular 2 `ControlGroup` was renamed to `FormGroup`

Comment: sir i got 'validator' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn error after use above?

Answer (score 13):

You can also use a custom directive validator to compare the fields.

In your html:

```
<div>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" [ngModel]="user.password" 
        required #password="ngModel">
    <small [hidden]="password.valid || (password.pristine && !f.submitted)">
        Password is required
    </small>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Retype password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" [ngModel]="user.confirmPassword" 
        required validateEqual="password" #confirmPassword="ngModel">
    <small [hidden]="confirmPassword.valid ||  (confirmPassword.pristine && !f.submitted)">
        Password mismatch
    </small>
</div>
```

And your directive:

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
    selector: '[validateEqual][formControlName],[validateEqual][formControl],[validateEqual][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => EqualValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class EqualValidator implements Validator {
    constructor( @Attribute('validateEqual') public validateEqual: string) {}

    validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        // self value (e.g. retype password)
        let v = c.value;

        // control value (e.g. password)
        let e = c.root.get(this.validateEqual);

        // value not equal
        if (e && v !== e.value) return {
            validateEqual: false
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the complete solution in plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/KgjSTj7VqbWMnRdYZdxM?p=preview

Comment: This solution is nice because it adds a global equal validator, unlike others that required re-writing code on each module. Note that the plunker code is different that what is posted here.

Comment: nice plunkr to understand. thanks i can use this one in my project.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't done this myself, but you could create [`ControlGroup`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/ControlGroup-class.html) with two password fields and validate it. Controls have `.valueChanges` property which is an observable and you can combine them and check for equality there.

Victor Savkin talks briefly about that exact case on Angular Air in [this episode](https://plus.google.com/events/chv2s61pjie9eirimvm2m5och9g)