# How to set Validator to required if visible?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am wondering how I can set the Validator in the following form to Required, only if the form element is present:

```
<div *ngIf="form.controls.user.value !== 'Admin' && form.controls.user.value ">
        <label>Role:</label>
        <input type="text" ngControl="role">
</div>
```

And my form is:

```
       this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
        user: ['',Validators.required],
        role: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

Comment: Looks to me like you'd need a custom form validation, maybe this helps you: https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-form-validation-9b26f73fcb81#.y3kgieuwd

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your case, you would create a global validator. Something like this:

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
  user: ['', Validators.required],
  role: ['']
}, { validator: (group) => {
  if (group.controls.user.value !== 'Admin') {
    return Validators.required((group.controls.role);
  }
  return null;
}});
```

In this case, the form is valid (this.form.valid === true) in the following case:

- user is not empty, is different of `Admin` and the role isn't empty
- user is `Admin`

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UKyRiq?p=preview.

See this question for more details:

- [Cross field validation in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413693/cross-field-validation-in-angular2/35414956#35414956)

Comment: Can you please provide working link??? The above one doesn show what it states. It might have forked by you. Please give us working link ...

Comment: Yes you're right @micronyks! I updated it without having forked it :-( I fixed that...

Comment: This answer is valid but @christian 's one is better in this context.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `disable()` and `enable()` functions. When a form control is disabled, validation is not applied to that control.

```
this.form.controls.user.disable();
this.form.controls.role.disable();
```

Comment: @thierry-templier response is good and  general solution for this kind of problem, but this one better and more elegant for this special use case.

Comment: this answer helped me a lot after struggling with validation problems. thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible that validations are automatically disabled when they are within an HTML block which is not shown due to an *ngIf condition?

Answer (score 1):

with in template it can be done this way -

`<input [(ngModel)]="page.headerImageWidth" [required]="page.isHeaderAvailable">`

Comment: this one doesnt seem to be working with reactive forms. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this.

- In html add isVisible variable in *ngIf property

  ```
    <div *ngIf="isVisible && form.controls.user.value !== 'Admin' && form.controls.user.value ">
        <label>Role:</label>
        <input type="text" ngControl="role">
  ```
- In .ts

  ```
  this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
        user: ['',Validators.required],
        role: ['', Validators.required]
    });



   if(this.form.controls.user.disabled == true){
    this.isVisible = false;
    }
    else {
    this.isVisible = true;
    }
  ```