# Method to set value and update validity of form control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am wondering if there is any method to set value and update validity of a control of a form. Given the following:

```
this.updateForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    user: ['',Validators.required]     
});
```

I have some directive which has on change trigger, that triggers the following:

```
changeUserSelection(value){
    this.updateForm.controls['user'].value = value // doesnt trigger validation?
}
```

And I am wondering how I can set the value, and trigger validation of this field. Doing this my way, doesnt trigger validation.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `updateValue` method instead:

```
changeUserSelection(value){
  this.updateForm.controls['user'].updateValue(value);
}
```

Comment: In which verison of angular was this introduced?

Comment: For some reason my TS doesnt see this, and I get an error: Property 'updateValue' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: Yes because the method is located into the `Control` class not in the `AbstractControl` one. `Control` extends `AbstractControl`. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/model.ts#L294

Comment: wait. but when I build a form using formBuilder, it returns AbstractControls...right?

Comment: Yes but you try to set the value on an input control within the form. In this case, it's a Control, i.e. `this.updateForm.controls['user']`.

Comment: Thats weird. We can see that export declare class ControlGroup extends AbstractControl {
    controls: {
        [key: string]: AbstractControl;
    }; . Hence, it is an abstractControl.

Comment: Yes because you can create sub group and in this case, it's a control group not a control. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413693/cross-field-validation-in-angular2/35414956#35414956. But for a control that corresponds to an input, it's a control.

Answer (score 9):

## Update to Angular2 final

As per angular2's final release  `updateValue` has been changed to `setValue`
so the new syntax should be like this

```
changeUserSelection(value){
  this.updateForm.controls['user'].setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: The `updateValueAndValidatity` need to be called to trigger the validator functions.

Comment: Also notice that `setValue` won't update the pristine status of the control. `markAsDirty` need to be called explicitly.

Comment: yeah exactly @YuanfeiZhu

Comment: Sometimes `markAsTouched()` is what's needed. With Angular material and the default ErrorMatcher - a control won't show its error message until it is 'touched'. It doesn't need to actually be 'dirty'.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver seems you are right, if you wish to edit my answer, i would be more than happy to approve, please go ahed.

Comment: @PardeepJain thanks for the reply. It seems for my situation I needed both `markAsTouched()` and `updateValueAndValidity`. There can be a lot of subtleties so maybe best to leave the answer as it is and hope people read and consider the comments. It's a whole project to consider all the possibilities - plus things like Angular Material adds extra complexity with ErrorStateMatcher (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050451/16940).

Comment: `dirty` means the value has changed, whereas `touched` just means it had focus. To be honest for most cases it probably wouldn't have an impact unless you had some very special needs.

Answer (score 7):

For me `setValue`, `patchValue` did not do the job by themselves. What I did to trigger the validation is the following:

```
form.controls[field].setValue(value);
form.controls[field].markAsTouched();
form.controls[field].markAsDirty();
form.controls[field].updateValueAndValidity();
```

That way my validation messages were triggered correctly. I tried without `updateValueAndValidity` but it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try patchValue

```
this.updateForm.patchValue({ user: value });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `this.form.updateValueAndValidity();` to update value and validation for multiple controls.