# Angular 2 - Forms - Set NgForm .submitted to true via NgForm Object

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular 1 (1.5) the form controller had a `$setSubmitted()` method that allowed you to programmatically set the `.$submitted` flag to true.

How can I do this in 2 via the NgForm object? I do not want to use the template, aka `(ngSubmit)=""`.

I've tried `<formname>.ngSubmit.emit()`, but it does not set `.submitted` to true.

Comment: *Not a direct answer - but may have led people to this question* I discovered a super confusing race condition. I was setting `[disabled]=true` to hide a `<button>` object during submission (so you couldn't click it twice). This however STOPPED .submitted from getting set if I'd set it to disabled inside a `(click)` handler on the submit button (which was being done via an @Input property). There are various possible solutions to this (like using onsubmit on the form instead of click on the button) - but it confused the heck out of me for a while.

Answer (score 5):

`ngSubmit` is actually an event emitter (an `@Output()` binding) that will notify you *after* form has been submitted - it does this by listening to the DOM event for submit on the host form element.

So even if you don't use `ngSubmit` the form will still be 'submitted` if the user clicks a submit button within the form.

You *can* set the form submitted flag to to `true` manually using the `onSubmit` method e.g. via a button

```
<button type="button" (click)="theForm.onSubmit($event)">Submit</button>
```

.. but in my experience with Angular forms this would be quite unusual to need to set this manually (the `ngForm` directive and `ngSubmit` event emitter should be all you need to manage the form). Is there a reason why you would need this?

Comment: I have the same issue. The reason I need to submit the form via ngSubmit.emit(), is because the button is outside the form in a parent component. I need the submitted flag to be set to true, because I use it in my validation message logic.

Comment: Calling onSubmit() instead of ngSubmit.emit() resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Similar situation to AntonK. To save a long explanation, I don't have control over the template or button that would trigger a submit, so I need to do it on in the JS code.

Comment: Same situation as @AntonK here but I also didn't find a solution to have the `submitted` property set to true...

Comment: I used this technique because I had an <i> tag with a font awesome icon that would be the cause of the submit and it needed to act like a submit button. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

To submit form on click of button which is outside of form this same method can be used.
While creating the form assign a Reference variable to the form

`<form name = "myform" (ngSubmit)= "SubmitForm()" #formVar = "ngForm">.....</form>`

Now we can use this **"formVar"** throughout the html to directly access the form.
For submitting on click of button outside of form (using ngSubmit directive of angular form)  use this.

```
<button (click)= "formVar.onSubmit($event)"> Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a workaround:

```
 <form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]='toiletForm' [class.submitted]='submitted'></form>
```

Component prop:

```
submitted: boolean;
```

.less:

```
form.submitted input.ng-invalid {
    border: solid 2px #fa787e !important;
}
```