# Angular - Submit a form programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-forms

Angular - Submit a form programmatically.

I have a form group on the HTML and I want the component to submit the form's action with an email field in a post method. Instead of using a normal submit button.

Below's testMethod gets called from another button. In this method, I want to post the **testForm**. It has to be posted old school way as it needs an action.

**This is my HTML:**

```xml
<form
  [formGroup]="testGroup"
  [action]='actionLink'
  method='POST'
  #testForm>
   <input name='Email' type='hidden' [value]='currentUserEmail'>
</form>
```

**This is my Component TS file attempt:**

```
  @ViewChild('testForm') testFormElement;

  public currentUserEmail: string = '';
  public testGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    Email: ''
  });


  public testMethod(): void {

      // Below: This currently doesnt seem to do anything.
      this.testFormElement.ngSubmit.emit();
  }
```

Comment: can you please tell us what is the reason of the error that we see in the console ? and what happened exactly when you click and the button ( when you call `testMethod()` ) ? Thanks

Comment: It seems like the this.testFormEl.nativeElement.submit() is doing nothing. I cant see the post in the network traffic

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I've added my current attempt above

Comment: @AngularM have you solved this?

Comment: this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054632/1730846) worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `ngNoForm` with your form to remove `ngForm` handling and to add plain javascript handler.

you can use your code as follows:

Html file.

```html
<form ngNoForm
  [formGroup]="testGroup"
  [action]='actionLink'
  method='POST'
  #testForm>
    <input name='Email' type='hidden' [value]='currentUserEmail'>
</form>
```

Ts File.

```ts
@ViewChild('testForm') testFormElement;

public currentUserEmail: string = '';
public testGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  Email: ''
});

constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}    

public testMethod(): void {
  this.testFormElement.nativeElement.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you should get ngForm in your code. So, rewrite your code as follows:

```html
<form
[formGroup]="testGroup"
[action]='actionLink'
method='POST'
#testForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="testForm.form.valid ? yourSaveMethod() :showValidatinErrors()">
  <input name='Email' type='hidden' [value]='currentUserEmail'>
</form>
```

and in your ts file:

```ts
@ViewChild('testForm') testFormElement: NgForm;

public testMethod(): void {
  // Below: This works for me.
  this.testFormElement.ngSubmit.emit();
}

public yourSaveMethod(): void {
  // post your model here.
}
```

Comment: If you want to really simulate submit you should also emit your values 

`this.testFormElement.ngSubmit.emit(this.testGroup.values);`

Answer (score 3):

I have found a good solution on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20562#issuecomment-456333500)

it will setup submitted as true

Out approach now is:

HTML:

```html
 <form [formGroup]="form" #myForm="ngForm" novalidate class="create-form">
```

ts:

```js
@ViewChild('myForm') ngForm: NgForm;

...
public onSubmit() {
 this.ngForm.onSubmit(undefined); // it will setup submitted as true
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "Angular - Submit a form programmatically"
Here is code where a form submits itself. It works for me. Hope this helps.

Component HTML:

```html
<form #myForm ngNoForm name="myForm" [action]="pdfServletUrl" target="_blank" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" [hidden]="'true'"></button>
</form>
```

Component TypeScript:

```ts
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm : ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myForm.nativeElement.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: `
        <form #testForm>
            <input name='Email' type='hidden'>
        </form>
    `
})
class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild('testForm') testFormEl;

    testMethod() {
        this.testFormEl.nativeElement.submit()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the error I get above in my question. Your solution didnt work

Comment: I have tried this code but responding an error that nativeElement is undefined. core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined