# Angular 5 submitting form programmatically don't send correct values

Tags: angular

In my angular 5 application I need to submit a hidden form programmatically after an Http GET call, but when the form is submitted the three variables I am sending seems empty (but they don't).

In my component I have :

```
@ViewChild('testForm') testFormEl: any;


this.ticketService.postTicketWithCreditPayment(param)
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.paymentUrl = res.url;
        this.paymentXml = res.xml;
        this.paymentHash = res.hash;

        console.log(this.paymentUrl) <-- this log make me see the correct paymentUrl 

        this.testFormEl.nativeElement.submit();
     })
    }
```

And in my html I have the form with 3 hidden fields

```
<form #testForm name="form1" action="https://...url..." method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" [value]="paymentUrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="xml" [(ngModel)]="paymentXml">
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" [(ngModel)]="paymentHash">
</form>
```

I try binding with `[value]` and `[(ngModel)]` but the form submitted is always this:
[image]

Is probably related to : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077840/angular-submit-a-form-programmatically)

Comment: If you downvote please explain me why!!!

Comment: (I didn't down vote) I think you shoud use reactive form provided with angular. You can find a simple tutorial here : https://coursetro.com/posts/code/66/Angular-4-Reactive-Forms-Tutorial

Comment: i think the values populated inside ngModel only as response of user changes event, so if object was initially empty you need to care about set its values somehow

Comment: How can I submit the reactive form in the component? @ibenjelloun

Comment: 1- Create your form using `FromBuilder`. 2- Link it to the template. 3- When click on submit use `HttpClient`'s appropriate http function to send `form.values` to the backend.

Comment: @ibenjelloun the form is hidden I need to submit it from the component.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to rewrite your HTML to:

```
<form #testForm name="form1" action="https://...url..." method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" [ngModel]="paymentUrl">
  <input type="hidden" name="xml" [ngModel]="paymentXml">
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" [ngModel]="paymentHash">
</form>
```

`[value]` instead of `[ngModel]` will also work here: one way binding from the controller.

in your TS file:

```
// get reference to the form
@ViewChild('testForm') testFormEl;
...
```

in your `subscribe` method, wrap form submit with `setTimeout()`, so submit will be moved to the next tick:

```
setTimeout(_ => this.testFormEl.nativeElement.submit());
```

It should work now.

I created a stackblitz (https://angular-f7lg76.stackblitz.io), in which I removed `method` and `action` attributes from the `form` element, so it executes `GET` to its self, and you can see sent data in the URL address bar.

Stackblitz source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7lg76?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Properly explained and the setTimeout is the best solution

Comment: @NileshSutar. I am glad that it saved your time :)