# Calling the submit button of the form outside the form in angular

Tags: angular, mat-dialog

I have a form in angular which I use to add and edit the record. I want this submit button outside the form.

I am using the mat dialog and want the submit button in the mat-dialog actions tag. The submit button that I place in the actions part of the dialog is not making the form to submit.

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>
  <h1 class="pb-4" style="padding-left: 50px">
    <span *ngIf="!userId">Add new</span><span *ngIf="userId">Update</span> user
  </h1>
</h2>

<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  <div class="dialog-padding">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isLoading$ | async">
      <div class="overlay-layer bg-transparent">
        <div class="spinner spinner-lg spinner-success"></div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <div>
      <form
        #myform="ngForm"
        class="form"
        id="kt_form"
        (ngSubmit)="save(myform)"
      >
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xl-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                  <input
                    required
                    type="text"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.name"
                    class="form-control form-control-solid"
                    placeholder=""
                    name="name"
                    #name="ngModel"
                  /> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row pt-4" style="border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5">
              <div class="col-xl-6"></div>
              <div class="col-xl-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary width-100">
                    {{ neworUpdate }} user
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button
    mat-button
    [mat-dialog-close]="true"
    cdkFocusInitial
    class="btn btn-primary btn-pointer"
  >
    Install
  </button>

  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="btn btn-primary btn-pointer">
    Cancel
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: You don’t need the ngSubmit at all and call the save method from anywhere in the component template.

Comment: The validation controls are not working on this button though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use submit button for your form, you should add your button between  tags for example (from docs):

```
<form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div>
    <label for="name">
      Name
    </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
  </div>

<button class="button" type="submit">Purchase</button>

</form>
```

> Actually I am using the mat dialog and want the submit button in the mat-dialog actions tag.

In documentation(https://angular.io/start/start-forms) it says:

> On the form tag, use an ngSubmit event binding to listen for the form submission

Since you are outside of form tags, you should modify your button like this:

```
<button
mat-button
[mat-dialog-close]="true"
cdkFocusInitial
class="btn btn-primary btn-pointer"
(click)="save()"
>
Install
</button>
```

Or you can try this answer: [Angular2 - Validate and submit form from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054631/angular2-validate-and-submit-form-from-outside)

Comment: But the idea is to keep the buttons outside the form, inside the mat-dialog-actions tag

Comment: this way (listening to click event manually when button is outside) you loose the submit by enter functionality... in order to keep it better option will be @dorin-baba solution

Answer (score 4):

Assign an Id to your form so you'll be able to put the submit button wherever you want by specifying button's type as `submit` and the form it is addressing to. Something like this:

```
<form 
   id="myform" <=====
   #myform="ngForm" 
   class="form" 
   ...>
     ....
</form>
```

Now, you can place the button anywhere on the template, not necessarily inside the form tags:

```
<button 
  mat-button 
  type="submit" <====
  form="myform" <====
  [mat-dialog-close]="true"
  cdkFocusInitial
  class="btn btn-primary btn-pointer">
     Install
</button>
```