# Angular2 - Form Validation on conditionally created input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angular

I am creating a simple form where user can select two possible values i.e. `Local` and `Foreigner`. If user selects nothing it makes the value of the form `invalid`. If user selects `Local` the form becomes `valid`. If user selects `Foreigner`, a new field appears for taking country as input from user which is also required. If user enters nothing in the country input field this makes the form `invalid`.

I have tried creating the form as below:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Control,ControlGroup,FormBuilder,FORM_DIRECTIVES,Validators} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
  <form [ngFormModel]="form" >
    <select [ngFormControl]="nationalityCtrl" >
      <option *ngFor="#nationality of nationalities" [value]="nationality" >{{nationality}}</option>
    </select><br>
    <input *ngIf="form.value.nationality == 'Foreigner'" type="text" [ngFormControl]="countryCtrl" placeholder="Country Name" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid" >Submit</button>
  </form>
  `,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
class MainApp{
  public nationalities = ["Foreigner","Local"];
  public form:ControlGroup;
  public nationalityCtrl:Control;
  public countryCtrl:Control;

  constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder){
  var self = this;

  this.nationalityCtrl = new Control("",Validators.compose([Validators.required]));
  this.countryCtrl = new Control("",Validators.compose([function(control:Control){
      if(self.nationalityCtrl.value == "Foreigner" && !control.value){
        return {invalid: true};
      }
    }]));

    this.form = this._fb.group({
      nationality: this.nationalityCtrl,
      country: this.countryCtrl
    });
  }
}
bootstrap(MainApp);
```

But as soon as I select the `Foreigner` option I get the following error on console:

> EXCEPTION: Expression '!form.valid in MainApp@6:36' has changed after
>   it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true' in
>   [!form.valid in MainApp@6:36]

I re-produced the problem on [plunker here](http://embed.plnkr.co/ApkaTy4ngsWXU7Vs6kt9/) you can see the error message on the console.

Comment: No plunker works fine as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would define a global validator for the whole form since your validator depends on two fields:

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
  nationality: this.nationalityCtrl,
  country: this.countryCtrl
}, {
  validator: (control:Control) => {
    var nationalityCtrl = control.controls.nationality;
    var countryCtrl = control.controls.country;
    if(nationalityCtrl.value == "Foreigner" && !countryCtrl.value){
      return {invalid: true};
    }
  }
});
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Cksiv2UFbWoVJv2VwPwh?p=preview.

See this question for more details:

- [Cross field validation in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413693/cross-field-validation-in-angular2/35414956#35414956)

Comment: In this way are you setting a validator for the whole formGroup?

Comment: Is `Control` deprecated? Should i use `FormControl` instead?