# Validators same as other value in form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I am wondering if there is a Validator that compares two different values from the same form - lets say I have the following:

```
 this.loginForm = fb.group({
      email: ["", Validators.required],
      password: ["", Validators.required],
      repeatPassword: ["", Validators.required]
  });
```

I found [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/FormBuilder-class.html) in documentation, however it wasn't very helpful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a validator to a complete form group to implement this. Something like that:

```
this.form = fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]
  matchingPassword: fb.group({
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    repeatPassword: ['', Validators.required]
  }
}, {validator: this.areEqual}));   <--------
```

This way you will have access to all controls of the group and not only one... This can be accessed using the `controls` property of the group control. The latter (not a single one) is directly provided when validation is triggered. For example:

```
areEqual(group: ControlGroup) {
  var valid = false;

  for (name in group.controls) {
    var val = group.controls[name].value

    (...)
  }

  if (valid) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    areEqual: true
  };
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular2 validator which relies on multiple form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788681/angular2-validator-which-relies-on-multiple-form-fields)