# Angular 2 form field validation with data dash attribute

Tags: javascript, validation, angular

I am trying to figure out form validation in Angular 2. Right now I have an add product form that is adding a product to a particular store's inventory. I want to validate that the product's price is more than the wholesale price of the product, so I added the wholesale price as a `data-*` attribute. What I can't figure out is how to reference that attribute with Angular 2's NgControl. Here is my code:

```
...
<div class="four wide field">
  <label>Wholesale Price</label>
  <div class="ui left icon input">
    <input type="text" disabled [(ngModel)]="wholesalePrice" ngControl="wholesale" />
    <i class="dollar icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="four wide field">
  <label>Price</label>
  <div class="ui left icon input">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="retailPrice" [attr.data-wholesale]="wholesalePrice" ngControl="price" required />
    <i class="dollar icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
...

...
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.form = fb.group({
        price: ['price', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            this.validator_moreThanWholesale
        ])],
        quantity: ['quantity']
    });

}
...
```

Comment: Why do you make it an attribute? What about creating an `@Input() wholeSale` and then access it from your code. The value will not yet be available in the `constructor() { ... }` only in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Answer (score 1):

I would create a global validator for your form:

```
this.form = fb.group({
  price: ['price', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required
  ])],
  quantity: ['quantity']
}, {
  validator: this.validator_moreThanWholesale
}));
```

The `validator_moreThanWholesale` method will have all the controls as input so you will be able to check:

```
validator_moreThanWholesale(group: ControlGroup) {
  var wholesale = group.controls.wholesale.value;
  var price = group.controls.price.value;

  return (price < wholesale) ? { moreThanWholesale: true } : null
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Validators same as other value in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064513/validators-same-as-other-value-in-form/36064541#36064541)