# How to override form.valid setting in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

```
<button type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        [disabled]="!complexForm.valid">
  Submit
</button>
```

My Submit button on the form is getting enabled when the form is not really valid. Old object == New object. Example user changes the value on a field, changes mind and enters same value again. The Submit button is now enabled and under the hood I could treat the Submit like a cancel and trick the user. However a better approach is to not show the Submit button at all until it is really valid. Where and how do I override Angular setting the `form.valid` property with my own logic where I check old new object and set `form.valid` myself

Comment: Sounds like the easier thing to do is base the disabled property of the form on a diff of your original object and the `form.value` instead of trying to override the form.

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with your validation if your form is "valid" when you say it's not really valid. Show us the rest of your validation code.

Comment: @Brandon, where do you put that logic ? { if (oldObj <> newObj> then form.valid = false;

Comment: I found a way to do this as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815194/angular2-interdependent-form-field-validation

Comment: @Gullu it could be a function on the view model or it could also be the validator for the FormGroup as a whole, which is what you'd use for interdependent fields on the form, or you could make it a shared function, part of a base view model class... there are many options.