# angular2- formbuilder, validators and testing end date is greater then start date

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a start and enddate input tags my html

I use angular the FormBuilder and custom Validators to ensure that that start date and end dates are valid.

In my component here is my snippet:

```
this.form = fb.group({
            startdate: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ModelValidators.validStartDate])],
            enddate: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ModelValidators.validEndDate])],

        });
```

Here are my validators:

```
static validStartDate(control: Control){
        var valid: any;
        valid=null;
        var diff:any;
        diff = new Date(control.value).valueOf() - new Date('1999-01-01').valueOf();
        if (diff>=0){
            valid=true;
        }
        return valid ? null : { validStartDate: true };

    }

    static validEndDate(control: Control){
        var valid: any;
        valid=null;
        var diff:any;
        diff = new Date().valueOf() - new Date(control.value).valueOf();
        if (diff>3600*24){
            valid=true;
        }
        return valid ? null : { validEndDate: true };
    }
```

Now..how can I validate that the enddate is greater than the start date and that the enddate - startdate is greater then 1 year?

E.g. Is is possible to pass other data to the ModelValidators.validEndDate function?

Comment: No, but the validator doesn't have to be a static static method. If it wasn't, it could access `this.form`, and the the startdate control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like this

```
this.form = fb.group({
   startdate: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ModelValidators.validStartDate])],
   enddate: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ModelValidators.validEndDate])],
        },{validator: this.validateDates}));
```

and then in you `validator class` create the function

```
validateDates(group: ControlGroup) {
  var valid = false;

  for (name in group.controls) {
    var val = group.controls[name].value

    (...)
  }

  if (valid) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    areEqual: true
  };
}
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788681/angular2-validator-which-relies-on-multiple-form-fields) for more detail