# Angular 2 form validations start date <= end date

Tags: validation, angular2-forms

I'm trying to add validations such that the end date can't be before the start date. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that, and I didn't find any helpful advice in the internet so far. My form looks like this:

```
editAndUpdateForm(tageler: Tageler) {
    this.tageler = tageler;
    this.tagelerForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [this.tageler.title, Validators.required],
      text: this.tageler.text,
      group: [[this.tageler.group], Validators.required],
      date_start: new Date(this.tageler.start).toISOString().slice(0, 10),
      date_end: new Date(this.tageler.end).toISOString().slice(0, 10),
      ...
    });
    this.tagelerForm.valueChanges
       .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
    }
```

My validations so far:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.tagelerForm) {
      return;
    }
    const form = this.tagelerForm;

    for (const field in this.formErrors) {

    // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
}

validationMessages = {
    'title': {
      'required': 'Geben Sie bitte einen Namen ein.',
    },
    'group': {
      'required': 'Wählen Sie bitte eine Gruppe aus.'
    },
    'bringAlong': {
      'required': 'Bitte Feld ausfüllen.'
    },
    'uniform': {
      'required': 'Bitte Feld ausfüllen.'
    },
};

formErrors = {
    'title': 'Geben Sie bitte einen Namen ein.',
    'group': 'Wählen Sie bitte eine Gruppe aus.',
    'bringAlong': 'Bitte Feld ausfüllen',
    'uniform': 'Bitte Feld ausfüllen',
};
```

The the form-controls 'date_start' & 'date_end' contain a date-string of the form 'dd.MM.yyyy', and I want 'date_end' to be bigger or equal 'date_start'.

I'd like to directly display the error message (my html code looks like this:)

```
<label for="formControlName_date_end" class="col-3 col-form-label">Ende:</label>
      <div class="col-5">
        <input id="formControlName_date_end" class="form-control" formControlName="date_end" type="date" value="{{tageler.end | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="formErrors.date_end" class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ formErrors.date_end }}
      </div>
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we cant do it in validation because we need two control values that is startdate and enddate for comparison. So it is better to compare two dates in your component

```
error:any={isError:false,errorMessage:''};

compareTwoDates(){
   if(new Date(this.form.controls['date_end'].value)<new Date(this.form.controls['date_start'].value)){
      this.error={isError:true,errorMessage:'End Date can't before start date'};
   }
}
```

In your html

```
<label for="formControlName_date_end" class="col-3 col-form-label">Ende:</label>
<div class="col-5">
      <input id="formControlName_date_end" class="form-control" formControlName="date_end" type="date" value="{{tageler.end | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" (blur)="compareTwoDates()">
</div>
<div *ngIf="error.isError" class="alert alert-danger">
   {{ error.errorMessage }}
</div>
```

Comment: although it shows up the error message the form validation still return "valid" is there a way to influence the real form validation?

Comment: This will just notify us the mistake that we have selected smaller end date then start data,but will not prevent submit the form itself.

Answer (score 38):

Based on the answer of santiagomaldonado I have created a generic ValidatorFn that can be used in multiple Reactive Forms with a dynamic return value.

```js
export class DateValidators {
    static dateLessThan(dateField1: string, dateField2: string, validatorField: { [key: string]: boolean }): ValidatorFn {
        return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
            const date1 = c.get(dateField1).value;
            const date2 = c.get(dateField2).value;
            if ((date1 !== null && date2 !== null) && date1 > date2) {
                return validatorField;
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
}
```

Import the validator and use it like this in your formgroup validators.

```js
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        loadDate: null,
        deliveryDate: null,
    }, { validator: Validators.compose([
        DateValidators.dateLessThan('loadDate', 'deliveryDate', { 'loaddate': true }),
        DateValidators.dateLessThan('cargoLoadDate', 'cargoDeliveryDate', { 'cargoloaddate': true })
    ])});
```

Now you can use the validation in HTML.

```
<md-error *ngIf="form.hasError('loaddate')">Load date must be before delivery date</md-error>
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also do it with Reactive Forms.
The [FormBuilder API](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#members) lets you add custom validators.

> Valid keys for the extra parameter map are **validator** and asyncValidator

Example:

```js
import { Component }  from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'reactive-form',
  templateUrl: './reactive-form.html'
})
export class ReactiveFormComponent {
  
  form: FormGroup

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      dateTo: ['', Validators.required ],
      dateFrom: ['', Validators.required ]
    }, {validator: this.dateLessThan('dateFrom', 'dateTo')});
  }
  
  dateLessThan(from: string, to: string) {
   return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    let f = group.controls[from];
    let t = group.controls[to];
    if (f.value > t.value) {
      return {
        dates: "Date from should be less than Date to"
      };
    }
    return {};
   }
 }
      
}
```

Note that I'm comparing the values of the inputs date and from with >, but by default this would be comparing strings.
In the live example I'm using [angular-date-value-accessor](https://github.com/johanneshoppe/angular-date-value-accessor) and importing the directive useValueAsDate.

```
<input formControlName="dateFrom" type="date" useValueAsDate />
```

With this directive group.controls[from].value and group.controls[to].value returns Date and then I can compare them with <.

[Live example in plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z7ps0E/)

Credits to [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582914/3517383)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in angular 5. Your plunker is broken too.

Answer (score 4):

create a form group . Let the controls be a part of form group .

```
       new FormGroup({   
        startDate: this.fb.group({
            dateInput: [{value: ""}, startDateValidator()]
        }),   
        endDate: this.fb.group({
            dateInput: ["", endDateValidator()]
        })  
    }, startDateCannotBeLessThanEndDateValidator());   

        startDateCannotBeLessThanEndDateValidator(formGroup: FormGroup) {

             let startDate = formGroup.get("startDate");   
            let endDate = formGroup.get("endDate");
            // compare 2 dates 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using moment, and in angular 7 to compare and validate dates, i use this function:

```
datesValidator(date1: any, date2: any): {[key:string]:any} | null {
    return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
        let start = group.controls[date1].value;
        let end = group.controls[date2].value;
        let datum1 = _moment(start).startOf('day');
        let datum2 = _moment(end).startOf('day');
        if (_moment(datum1).isSameOrAfter(datum2)) {
           this.alert.red("Error: wrong period!"); //popup message
           return { 'error': 'Wrong period!' };        
        }
        return null; //period is ok, return null
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is angular7 + [ngprime](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/)(for calendar)

(*if you don't want ngprime just replace calendar part to others.)

Refer below code for date validation.

My code has additional validation that 
  once start date is selected, I block previous days in end data's calendar 
  so that the end date will be always later than that.

if you don't want to block date, delete [minDate] part.
 it is also working.

**> Component**

```
export class test implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  defaultDate: Date = new Date();
  checkDate = true;
  form: FormGroup;

  today: Date = new Date(); //StartDate for startDatetime
  startDate: Date = new Date();  //StartDate for endDatetime

  initFormControls(): void {
    this.today.setDate(this.today.getDate());
    this.startDate.setDate(this.today.getDate()); //or start date + 1 day

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      startDatetime: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      endDatetime: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    },
      { validators: this.checkDateValidation });
  }

  checkDateValidation: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
    try {

      let startingDatefield = control.get('startDatetime').value;

      this.startDate = new Date(startingDatefield); //new Date(startingDatefield).getDate()
      let endingDatefield = control.get('endDatetime').value;

      if (this.today >= startingDatefield) { //compare to current date 
        console.log("Please set a Start Date that is on or after Current Date and Time.");
        return { 'effectiveStartDatetime': false };

      } else
        if (startingDatefield > endingDatefield && endingDatefield) {
          console.log("Please set an End Date and Time that is after the Start Date and Time.");
          return {};

        } else {
          return {};
        }
    } catch (err) {
    }
  };



  onSubmit() {

    //if form is not valid
    if (!this.form.valid) {
      console.log(" Please fill in all the mandatory fields");

      // do sth
    return;
    }


    //if form is valid
    //do sth

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.initFormControls();
  }
```

**> HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p-button type="submit" label="submit"></p-button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Start Date/Time"</p>
    <div>
      <p-calendar formControlName="startDatetime" appendTo="body" showTime="true" hourFormat="24" stepMinute="30"
        showSeconds="false" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [minDate]="today"></p-calendar>
      <div
        *ngIf="form.get('startDatetime').invalid && (form.get('startDatetime').dirty || form.get('startDatetime').touched)">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('startDatetime').hasError('required')">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>End Date/Time</p>
    <div>
      <p-calendar formControlName="endDatetime" appendTo="body" showTime="true" hourFormat="24" stepMinute="30"
        showSeconds="false" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [minDate]="startDate"></p-calendar>
      <div *ngIf="form.get('endDatetime').invalid && (form.get('endDatetime').dirty || form.get('endDatetime').touched)">
        <div *ngIf="!checkDate || form.get('endDatetime').hasError('required')">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```