# Validating depending input field

Tags: angular, validation, date, angular2-forms

I have a template driven form with two date inputs. The second one needs to be after the first one. I found some examples for creating custom validators but these approaches seem to be very complex and I don't think that something is necessary for this little problem and also this approach does not allow to validate two inputs interdependently.

```
<form #contractForm="ngForm">
    <md-input-container>
        <input type="date" mdInput name="validFrom">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <input type="date" mdInput name="validUntil">
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

I just thought about something like this

```
<input type="date" mdInput name="validUntil" [valid]="validFrom.value < validUntil.value">
```

You know a simple way to check this?

Comment: I found a very hacky workaround with using the pattern attribute. I could check the input values onChance and set the pattern attribute for setting the input either valid or invalid. - I would not like this xD

Comment: you can refer something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779438/angular-2-form-validations-start-date-end-date/43782594?noredirect=1#comment74607619_43782594

Comment: this seems not to change validity of the form but only shows up an error. I have my submit button bound to the validity.

    <button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!contractForm.form.valid"  i18n>Submit</button>