# How to compare two dates in angular 4 and display error message?

Tags: angular, date-comparison, ngx-mydatepicker

I want to display an error message when end date is less than start date. I'm using my-date-picker.

I have tried following approach but not sure why its not working. As I'm new to angular I tried this approach by going online tutorials, this is what I have achieved so far.

this is my html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
  <div class="form-input">
      <my-date-picker name="startDateMod" [options]="startDate" formControlName="startDateMod" required (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)"></my-date-picker>
      <my-date-picker name="endDateMod" [options]="endDate" formControlName="endDateMod" required (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)"></my-date-picker>
  </div>
  <button class="button" type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.controls.errors||">Submit</button>
  <p class="error" *ngIf="myForm.controls.errors">Date is required!</p>
</form>
```

In ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        startDateMod: [null, Validators.required],
        endDateMod: [null, Validators.required]

    });
}
 onDateChanged(event){
   let startDate = this.myForm.startDateMod.value.epoc;//Getting epoc values to compare 
   let endDate = this.myForm.endDateMod.value.epoc;
   if(endDate>startDate){
    /*Not sure what to add here to display error message on html page because i'm not getting any error when i'm performing this step
}
```

}

I'm getting start and end date but date comparison is not working and also not sure how to get an error message to display on page.I expect when I click on any date, start and end date should compare and if end date is less than start date error message should display and search button get disabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 form validations start date <= end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779438/angular-2-form-validations-start-date-end-date)

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622299/date-difference-in-hours-angular-2

Comment: I have tried that but it was not working in my case...thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

if (startDate.getTime() < endDate.getTime())

Note that if your dates are in string format, you first need to parse them to Date

Comment: can u tell me the full solution on how to get it working