# Angular 2 FormBuilder w/ Custom/Dynamic Validation loop

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

**Background**

I have a form with multiple fields that affect the validation of one another.

As a simple example, let's take a simple form with a CellNo (Cellphone number) and HomeNo (a Home contact number).

Both have validation applied to them for detecting the validity of the numbers themselves, however:
**If a CellNo is entered** - the HomeNo field isn't required, **and visa versa.**

I implement a subscription to the **valueChanges** of each field which then updates the Validators of each field based on the FormControl values of each, and then calls the **updateValueAndValidity()** function.

By calling this function however, it triggers the valueChanges subscription of each field, causing an infinite loop.

**Question**

What would be the best way to go about achieving this with a FormBuilder?

**Edit 1**: Replicated my issue in a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/U7HPGLYL9rGIN1xyxGlp).

Open your console/devtools to see the looping output. The function that gets called repeatedly is:

```
updatePhoneValidations() {
    console.log('Updating validations');
    let cellValidators = [Validators.pattern(this.PHONE_REGEX), Validators.maxLength(25)];
    if (this.inputForm.controls.HomeNo.value.length === 0) {
        this.inputForm.controls.CellNo.setValidators([...cellValidators, Validators.required]);
    } else {
        console.log('Removing CellNo');

        this.inputForm.controls.CellNo.setValidators([...cellValidators]);

    }
     this.inputForm.controls.CellNo.updateValueAndValidity();

    let homeNoValidators = [Validators.pattern(this.PHONE_REGEX), Validators.maxLength(25)];
    if (this.inputForm.controls.CellNo.value.length === 0 ) {
        this.inputForm.controls.HomeNo.setValidators([...homeNoValidators, Validators.required]);
    } else {
        console.log('Removing HomeNo', this.inputForm.controls.HomeNo);

        this.inputForm.controls.HomeNo.setValidators([...homeNoValidators]);

    }
     this.inputForm.controls.HomeNo.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what is your code so far

Comment: Sure thing, will try post a Plunkr or something soon

Comment: @Drakkin Plunkr added

Comment: Have you tried to do the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582914/1770833) ? the function `matchingPasswords`

Answer (score 3):

This may not have been the case at the time the question was asked, but now you can use the option `emitEvent:false` to prevent a new event being emitted.

```
updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false })
```